# Can anyone help to identify this tree with strange green flower/fruit in North Georgia woods?

Tags: plant-identification, tree-identification

What tree is this?  I am unable to identify it.  It has a green spongy soft velvety flower/fruit at the end of branches.  It is located in North Georgia woods in the USA. I don't believe it would be a fungus because there were about 15 other same leafed trees across an area that all had this characteristic.

[image: Strange tree in North Georgia]

[image: Flower/Fruit of tree]

Comment: Perhaps a variety of pawpaw.

Comment: @WeatherVane my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Are those individual fruits or clusters of fruits? If clusters, how many fruit per cluster?

Comment: Definitely pawpaw or variety of it as @Weather Vane said. I studied forestry, but not in USA.  Pawpaw is native to that area (Georgia).

Comment: What time of year was that taken? Also post on Gardening and Landscaping stack. They're wizards at plant ID.